# Correct way to go about updating a shared Redux state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, redux, state

I have a web page in a react app where I enter text into two separate text boxes that will update the backend with the text entered. The update occurs after a short time where the user no longer types to avoid spamming the server. Once a server update goes out, I update the state with the information that came from the server. This, of course, causes that part to re-render. This works great until a user enters something inside one box and then enters information into the second box before the otther box's update has gone off. The information in the second box is lost and overwritten by the update coming from the server.

It's important to note that the textbox itself stores the state of the text, and only when an action/dispatch cycle is called after the timeout does the redux state update. I tried tieing the textbox text state to redux, but the performance took a hit, and there was noticeable lag when typing.

Currently, I have each text box being passed a prop that maps to a value in from the redux state. These text boxes have different values mapped to them, but they are from the same state.

I don't really know the best way to approach this such that the textboxes store their values after being fetched from the server and still will not lose text when the other is updated.

In the component that renders the page:

```js
render() {
//... other code
return (
/*... some jsx ...*/
<DetailTextArea className="textArea" detailType="implementation" text={practiceInView.implementation_details}/>

/*... more jsx ... */
<DetailTextArea className="textArea" detailType="evidence" text={practiceInView.evidence_details}/>
);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get this clear but I'd never overwrite the contents with whatever comes back from the server. Rather, just inform user that the data is synchronized or not.

Comment: I think @Wiktor is onto something. That makes a lot of sense unless the server is doing some sort of normalization that would modify the text.  What does the `DetailTextArea` component do with the `text` prop?  It sounds like it overrides the local state when text changes?  Even if it does, if these are just `string` and you have a a `useEffect` that depends on `text` then a change in another field shouldn't trigger an update since the `text` value would be the same as before.  Can you post the `DetailTextArea` component?

Comment: To second (third?) what has been said above, this form of optimistic rendering is something that I have used in the past when network speed was expected to be slow.  We updated the page via state immediately and only informed the user and reverted the change if the server response did not match the change that you made.  Otherwise, it just appeared that the page was "snappy".